# add a text field with onchange attribute to a slider

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have got this slider some where of the internet, and i want to add a text box to this slider, so on value change inside this slider, the slider sets itself to the given value in the text box.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Papermashup.com | jQuery UI Slider Demo</title>
    <link href="../style.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            background:url(bg.jpg)!important;
            padding:100px 50px 0px 50px;
        }
        /*the slider background*/
        .slider {
            width:230px;
            height:11px;
            background:url(slider-bg.png);
            position:relative;
            margin:0;
            padding:0 10px;
        }
        /*Style for the slider button*/
        .ui-slider-handle {
            width:24px;
            height:24px;
            position:absolute;
            top:-7px;
            margin-left:-12px;
            z-index:200;
            background:url(slider-button.png);
        }
        /*Result div where the slider value is displayed*/
        #slider-result {
            font-size:50px;
            height:200px;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color:#fff;
            width:250px;
            text-align:center;
            text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
            font-weight:700;
            padding:20px 0;
        }
        /*This is the fill bar colour*/
        .ui-widget-header {
            background:url(fill.png) no-repeat left;
            height:8px;
            left:1px;
            top:1px;
            position:absolute;
        }
        a {
            outline:none;
            -moz-outline-style:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div id="slider-result">50</div>
    <div class="ui-widget-header"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden" />
    <script>
        $(".slider").slider({
            animate: true,
            range: "min",
            value: 50,
            min: 0,
            max: 80,
            step: 1,
            //this gets a live reading of the value and prints it on the page
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#slider-result").html(ui.value);
            },
            //this updates the hidden form field so we can submit the data using a form
            change: function (event, ui) {
                $('#hidden').attr('value', ui.value);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope i explained it good enough.

Comment: just add your textfield wherever you want it, give it an id, und extend the slide: function with the id of textfield and .val(ui.value);

Comment: @Rufinus tnx. and what value i must give to the onchange in the textbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're using jQuery UI. Like the script you copied you can read in the comments that this part:

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#slider-result").html(ui.value);
}
```

your result live updates.

so if you do a little modification:

add this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="showslider" />
```

and modify the live sliding thing/

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
     $("#slider-result").html(ui.value);
     $("#showslider").val(ui.value);
}
```

then the thing should work.

EDIT:

You could add an event listener to the textbox that you change the value each time the user
is typing or when he presses enter (that's how you want it) an example of this:

```
$("#showslider").keyup(function (e){
     $(".slider").slider("value", $("#showslider").val());
}
```

More information could be found here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: tnx for the tip. But i want the "showslider" which is a text box, control the slider too. I want to be able to set the slider by the "showslider" too.